# MDX syntax highlighting is not working in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mdxjs

When importing the plugin `@mapbox/rehype-prism`, it doesn't seem to do anything for syntax highlighting as it is supposed to.

```js
//next.config.js
const rehypePrism = require("@mapbox/rehype-prism");

const withMDX = require("@next/mdx")({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    rehypePlugins: [rehypePrism],
  },
});
module.exports = withMDX({
  pageExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "md", "mdx"],
});
```

Comment: For those who are seeking the answer, just import the theme css that you can download from prism.

Answer (score 1):

Have you solve this problem yet?

It may not be done, so I will write the method :)

anyway import `prism.css` in `_app.tsx` (or js, jsx, ts).
`prism.css` can be downloaded from [prismjs.com/download](https://prismjs.com/download.html). Before download it, you can select theme and language you use.
This settings is memorized in top of `prism.css` as url params format, so you can reconfigure theme and language with accesing access with this url.

```
import React from 'react';
import xxx
import yyy

import '../styles/prism.css`
```

do you solve?

if no, Please try to solve with following my reference code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import matter from 'gray-matter';
import { MDXRemote, MDXRemoteSerializeResult } from 'next-mdx-remote';
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize';
import rehypePrism from '@mapbox/rehype-prism';

import Statics from './next-statics.config';
import MdxComponents from './mdx-components.config';

type MdxPrismProps = {
  source: MDXRemoteSerializeResult;
};

const MdxPrism: React.FC<MdxPrismProps> = ({ source }) => {
  return <MDXRemote {...source} components={MdxComponents} />;
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const postFilePath = path.join(Statics.path.posts, `${params.slug}.mdx`);
  const source = fs.readFileSync(postFilePath);

  const { content } = matter(source);

  const mdxSource = await serialize(content, {
    mdxOptions: {
      rehypePlugins: [rehypePrism],
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      source: mdxSource,
    },
  };
};

export default MdxPrism;
```

maybe you can solve to use following part of previous code.

```
  const mdxSource = await serialize(content, {
    mdxOptions: {
      rehypePlugins: [rehypePrism],
    },
  });
```

If this still doesn't work, please find `<pre>` and `<code>` in html by developer tools (press F12).
and check these tags have `class="language-xxx"`.